# Reuse the decorated function

Tags: python, python-decorators

This question is about reusing the decorated function in the outer scope.

It is awesome if I could get the following piece of code to work. I know the function is passed in to `eat` as a parameter, but is there a way to keep `apple` recognized in the scope?

```
class A:

  def eat( s, func ):
    print 123

  def __init__(s):
    @s.eat
    def apple():
      print 456

    apple() # "apple" is not defined ...
```

Thanks!

Sincerely,

Comment: You mean like the original `apple`?

Comment: What do you mean `apple` is not recognized? The error you'll run in to is that `apple` is no longer callable, because your decorator returns `None` and `apple` has now been set to none. i.e. `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: The only other explanation is if your code is not indented properly...

Comment: It'll work if you fix your decorator and let it `return func`.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks for pointing this out ... I should return func in eat!